# MFC assertion to work in global destructors

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017, mfc, assert

I'm writing an MFC GUI app with Visual Studio 2017. And I was naturally using its [ASSERT/VERIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/c-cpp-assertions?view=vs-2019#BKMK_MFC_assertions) macros to do some debugger code checks. But unfortunately those do not work in global destructors. For instance, if I have something like this:

```
struct MY_STRUCT{
    HANDLE hHandle;

    MY_STRUCT()
        : hHandle(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~MY_STRUCT()
    {
        //Make sure handle was released
        ASSERT(hHandle == NULL);
    }
};

//On the global scale
MY_STRUCT mys;
```

If assertion in the destructor of `MY_STRUCT` is triggered, it will only produce a warning beep but the assertion dialog box will not be shown, and the process will terminate. So it's very hard to see which `ASSERT` produced it.

*(This happens because the [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) function that is used internally by `ASSERT` cannot show a dialog window when the process is terminating.)*

To address it I was using [`FatalAppExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API for my own version of that macro that I defined as such:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define ASSERT2(f) {if(!(f))\
{\
        char __buffer123456789[256*4];\
        wsprintfA(__buffer123456789, "ASSERTION!!!\nFile: %s\nLine: %d\nGetLastError() = %d", __FILE__, __LINE__, ::GetLastError());\
        FatalAppExitA(0, __buffer123456789);\
}}
#else
#define ASSERT2(f) ((void)0)
#endif
```

And even though my `ASSERT2` seems to be showing an assertion dialog box while stopping the process from exiting:

[image]

It does not give me an option to break if I'm running my process under VS 2017 debugger.

Does anyone have a solution where I can:

- Break my GUI process.
- Display an assertion dialog box.
- Have an option to invoke my JIT debugger if I'm running the process under it.

*PS. I am **not asking** about text file error logging here.*

Comment: Suggest you use `OutputDebugString` for logging during program shutdown see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And `DebugBreak` to break into the debugger (if already attached) see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak

Comment: @RichardCritten: Oh, shoot, I just realized that I can use `IsDebuggerPresent()` to check inside that macro and if it returns `true` then invoke `DebugBreak()` before calling `FatalAppExit`.

Comment: really no any problem run *MesageBoxW* here. process yet not terminating. exe destructors called before call `ExitProcess`. another  task that may be `QW_QUIT` in queue. need first *MSG msg;
 while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE));*
loop

Comment: @RbMm: Did you try it?

Comment: @c00000fd try what ? run messagebox ? yes of course.all is ok, but with `MSG msg;
 while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE));` before it

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, OK. Your edit makes a difference.

Comment: possible attach debugger until `MessageBox` run and have *if (IsDebugger()) __debugbreak();* after it

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution soon after I posted this question. Here it is:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define ASSERT2(f) {if(!(f))\
{\
        if(::IsDebuggerPresent()) { ::DebugBreak(); } \
        char __buffer123456789[256*4];\
        wsprintfA(__buffer123456789, "ASSERTION!!!\nFile: %s\nLine: %d\nGetLastError() = %d", __FILE__, __LINE__, ::GetLastError());\
        FatalAppExitA(0, __buffer123456789);\
}}
#else
#define ASSERT2(f) ((void)0)
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define VERIFY2(f) ASSERT2(f)
#else
#define VERIFY2(f) ((void)(f))
#endif
```

I'll keep this question in case someone has a better idea.